# Point cloud line searching algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, point-clouds

I'm working with a 2D point cloud and I want to find the shape that it follows, and determine whether it is a closed loop or not. You'll have to excuse my terrible paint illustration, but essentially I want to be able to  draw the red line from the  black dots, and confirm whether it is closed or not. I'm currently looking through methods like RANSAC etc but they all seem suited to slightly different tasks than the one I face. I'll be implementing the solution in C++.

Does anyone know a good approach/algorithm to calculate the red line, given the black points, and determine whether it closed?

[image]

Comment: The question isn't clear. You told us what you want to do but you gave no examples of code implementation with issues and there isn't even a question in your post. You are only stating what you want to do.

Comment: I've edited to make the question clearer

Comment: What is if it forks? Is that fine? I have a very simple algorithm for you, but I don't know it it matches what you actually need: 1. around every dot, paint everything in distance X in dark, 2. using algorithms such as BFS, check how many big components you have (where a big component has Y pixels), and if the answer is two, you are fine. (Create an artificial border to rule out a line that goes from one side to the other.)

Comment: I'll see what I can do with that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to:

1. Triangulate the point set.
2. Find the short path through all lines, basically the traveling salesman problem. The greedy algorithm is probably good enough for this purpose.
3. Use a line simplification algorithm to "tidy up" the line (RDP algorithm works pretty well).
4. Consider anything greater than X times the average distance between points (from step 2), basically outliers in the data as gaps to determine if open or closed.

Keep in mind steps #3 and #4 are highly opinionated. They both require you to define what you consider is "good enough", and will require some experimentation to set the best values.